# How to match times in audio to text

Tags: time, synchronization, speech-recognition

I have a bunch of audio files and the text that corresponds to the speech in the audio files. I need to be able find the specific times in the audio where each word starts. I trying to use the C# [SpeechRecognizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer(v=vs.110).aspx) library but I can't find a way to get time data for the words it recognizes. Is it possible with this library? Is there a different tool/library that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I use CMU Sphinx for this. (Java though, not sure if they provide C# API.) It allows me to access internals of the recognized text, in which I am able to find start/stop times.

https://cmusphinx.github.io/
https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialsphinx4/